# How to write a function to format string in a clear way?

Tags: python, string, format

I'm sure that this can be written in a clear way, but I can't find any other way:

```
'The items included in the {} are exactly the same as the items in the {}.
 Do you want to proceed?'.format(
    'Box2' if request.data.get('box_type') == Box.BoxType.Box2 else 'Box3',
    'Box3' if request.data.get('box_type') == Box.BoxType.Box3 else 'Box2'
 )
```

Comment: Assuming that it has the expected behavior, I don't really see the problem.

Comment: Seems like there's probably an easier way to convert `Box.BoxType.Box2` into the string `'Box2'`, but you haven't provided any information about what the type of that object is.  If it's an `Enum`, for example, you could just use `request.data.get('box_type').name`.

Comment: My objective was to do this clearly using less code. 
The `Box.BoxType.BoxX` are TextChoices of Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this often in your script, I'd suggest using a global constant:

```py
PROMPT = 'The items included in the {} are exactly the same as the items in the {}. Do you want to proceed?'
```

And then a helper:

```py
def get_prompt(box_type):
    if box_type == Box.BoxType.Box2:
        return 'Box2', 'Box3'
    return 'Box3', 'Box2'
```

Then calling the helper:

```py
box_type = request.data.get('box_type')
boxes = get_prompt(box_type)
print(PROMPT.format(*boxes))
```

Comment: Speaking about constants, in case if just two options possible I'd prefer to define two static messages and not call format every time.

Comment: Yeah. I'm assuming there's more to it, but that'd be an okay option too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use variables? Also, it is advised to use f-strings:

```py
first_box = "Box2" if request.data.get("box_type") == Box.BoxType.Box2 else "Box3"
second_box = "Box3" if request.data.get("box_type") == Box.BoxType.Box3 else "Box2"
print(f"The items included in the {first_box} are exactly the same as the items in the {second_box}. Do you want to proceed?")
```

Comment: "it is advised to use f-strings" -- not necessarily. There will always be legitimate use-cases for `str.format`. String templates are very useful for certain types of programs, and not possible with f-strings.

Comment: @ddejohn I agree, although but you could tell [PEP498](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) advises f-strings in most cases. Also, f-strings are faster than other formatting methods.

Comment: Yeah that was my other option. But just asked if there is another way of writing same logic using less code.